# Selenium get "page source" as shown on elements page in chrome

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way in Selenium (java) to get the "page source" as shown on the elements page (F12) in chrome.

I have to test an application the page is heavily modified by javascript. I already tried:

```
String html = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
```

and

```
String html = driver.getPageSource();
```

but both show the "effective" html.

Comment: Disbale javascript in the driver and then load the page. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Disabeling javascript is not an option i want to get the source afther javascript modified it

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. I am using selenium driver(phantomjs and htmlunit browsers) and I am getting effective html with getPageSource()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait until the expected elements are loaded - see https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

E.g.

```
    driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).  
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```